# Get id in bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

In WP I have a custom post type. When I click *Read more link* I pass id with `<?php the_ID()?>` to modal in hidden field value. Now I am interested how can I grab that id to load post with this specific id.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7qq01om1/5/)

```
<div id="read_more" data-id="<?php the_ID()?>">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal">Read More...</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That should grab the `id`

```
$(this).attr("data-id");
```

Comment: Thank you but how can I use it in php?... I have php page with code:  `<div id="read_more" data-id="6">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal">Read More...</a>
</div>` and Want to send id to another page  with modal.

Comment: I am unsure what you are asking. Does `<?php the_ID() ?>` grab the ID that you want? Also, I recommend that if you want to post data using php that you include the php tag in this question as well. You also never specified in the question that the modal was on a different page so I would also mention that. I am not very knowledgeable in php so am unable to help